# Spring cloud config server-client refresh strategy

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am very new to spring cloud world and trying to setup a config server with a small Microservices. I was able to setup a MySQL database table as a datasource and my client Microservices is able to get the configurations as expected.

Config server `bootstrap.yml`

```
  profiles:
    active: jdbc
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://qweqwewqrwqrwqwq.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/TEST
    username: user
    password: user123
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      connection-timeout: 5000
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT `key`, value FROM properties WHERE application=? and profile=? and label=?
          order: 1
```

I have also used `@RefreshScope` in my client micro server to enable actuator refresh. I noticed when I restart (stop and restart springboot app) the client micro service it automatically fetches the most updated configuration.

This means in AWS world when a new Microservices instance comes up due to autoscaling, it will fetch the most the updated configuration. Where the existing instances will still have the old configuration.

Tried to find a solution for this, found about spring cloud bus which can push updated configuration to all Microservices instances, but still did not find any clue on how to stop my Microservices to get the updated configuration when it restarts.

Comment: You can't, you will always get download the latest version of the configuration when the service restart (why wouldn't you want to?). You just need to make sure you always call `/refresh` or post to the bus after you change the config so all the existing instances are also updated.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. I am wondering so how should I control my configuration change releases? 
Should I always create a new row with a different label every time and change the label during deployments to release a new set of configurations?

Comment: you can store configuration in GIT. When you create webhook, it will call config server, ant it'll refresh configurations of all relevant microservices via queue. See https://springbootdev.com/2018/07/21/spring-cloud-config-using-git-webhook-to-auto-refresh-the-config-changes-with-spring-cloud-stream-spring-cloud-bus-and-rabbitmq-part-3/

Comment: I will have to use a database as a datasource, git webhook will not work in my case.